# Arabic unicode or ASCII code in java

Tags: java, android

i want to find the character ASCII code for programming android to support the Arabic locale. Android programming has many characters are different English. The ASCII code in many letters joint or some of letters are split.
how can i find the special code for each letter?

Comment: It's not at all clear to me what you mean, I'm afraid - but ASCII only contains 127 characters - no Arabic ones. What *exactly* are you trying to do? You can look on http://unicode.org to find the Unicode code point for any character, but without knowing the context it's unclear as to whether that will help you.

Answer (score 4):

Unicode is a numbering of *all* characters. The numbering would need three bytes integers. A Unicode character is represented in science as **U+*XXXX*** where *XXXX* stands for the number in hexadecimal (base 16) notation. A Unicode character is called **code point**, in Java with type **int**.

Java `char` is 2 bytes (UTF-16), so cannot represent the higher order Unicode; there a pair of two chars is used.

The java class Character deals with conversion.

```
char lowUnicode = '\u0627'; // Alef, fitting in a char
int cp = (int) lowUnicode;
```

One can iterate through code points of a String as follows:

```
    String s = "...";
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); ) {
        int codePoint = s.codePointAt(i);
        i += Character.charCount(codePoint);
    }

    String s = "...";
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); ) {
        int codePoint = s.codePointAt(i);
        ...
        i += Character.charCount(codePoint);
    }
```

Or in java 8:

```
    s.codePoints().forEach(
        (codePoint) -> System.out.println(codePoint));
```

***Dumping Arabic between U+600 and U+8FF:***

The code below dumps Unicode in the main Arabic range.

```
for (int codePoint = 0x600; codePoint < 0x900; ++codePoint) {
    if (Character.isAlphabetic(codePoint)
            && UnicodeScript.of(codePoint) == UnicodeScript.ARABIC) {

        System.out.printf("\u200E\\%04X \u200F%s\u200E %s%n",
                codePoint,
                new String(Character.toChars(codePoint)),
                Character.getName(codePoint));
    }
}
```

Under Windows/Linux/... there exist char map tools to display Unicode.
Above U+200E is the Left-To-Right, and U+200F is the Right-To-Left mark.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get Unicode characters code below will do that:

```
char character = 'ع';
int code = (int) character;
```